# Using where_in() with a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I would like to know how can you use CodeIgnitors built in `where_in()` function with a multi-dimensional array. Here is how I am doing it so far but I get an array string conversion error.

Example array:(array is dynamic and will change depending on what is entered by the user)

```
array([0]=>'hello',[1]=>'goodbye');
```

My Model:

```
 $this->db->where_in('Column',$array);
        $query = $this->db->get('Table');
        $result = $query->result();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $vID = $row->ID;
            $this->db->insert('Table2', array('ID' => $id, 'val' => $vID));
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 555
```

And this one:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`Tags`) WHERE `Tags` IN (Array)
```

Comment: What does your `$array` look like?  Are you sure it's "multi-dimensional"?  `where_in` doesn't work with a multi-dimensional array.  Also, you cannot do `val' => $array` in your `insert`.  Perhaps you want [`$this->db->insert_batch`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)?

Comment: Sorry that was an error, and What is a work around to use a multi dimensional array?

Comment: What does your array *really* look like?  You might need to `foreach` over it and run this for each array inside.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always frustrated when people use **CI** and just don't read the guide, it clearly states you can only use the following:

1. Simple key/value *(name = something)*
2. Custom key/value *(name != something)*
3. Associative array *(name => something)*
4. Custom string *("name = 'something'")*

You cannot use a **"multi-dimensional"** array and just *toss* it in and have it work for you. Please read the guide here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html